# Getting AbstractMethodErrorException when migrating from Spring Boot 1.5.9.RELEASE to 2.1.4.RELEASE; spring version 5.1.6.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, maven

I posted this on the spring boot github and was informed that I must have spring framework <= 5.0 on my classpath somewhere because

> Since Spring Framework 5.1, `supportsSourceType(Class<?> type)` became a default method on `SmartApplicationListener` which `ConfigFileApplicationListener` implements. As a result, the implementation of that method was removed from `ConfigFileApplicationListener` in Spring Boot 2.1 as it was no longer needed. As an `AbstractMethodError` is being thrown for that method, you must have Spring Framework 5.0 or earlier on the classpath somewhere.

I have printed my maven dependency tree below and was trying to find this but am having no luck. My main project here in question is a simple Java Spring Boot application that uses spring batch to load CSV files. It is using 1 main dependency, my sales-offers-db model, which is basically just the JPA/Hibernate data classes and such.

did the person mean that ANY dependency that is prefixed with `org.springframework` can NOT be <= 5.0? That's what I was confused about because spring batch core and some dependencies don't even have versions that high... any help?

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:3.0.1:tree (default-cli) @ marketing-offers-loader ---
[INFO] com.blahblah.blah.sales.offers:sales-offers-loader:jar:01.1.56-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:jar:1.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.10.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.8.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:9.0.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.1.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:2.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.63:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.tomcat:tomcat-annotations-api:jar:9.0.21:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-core:jar:1.1.5:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.hdrhistogram:HdrHistogram:jar:2.1.9:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.latencyutils:LatencyUtils:jar:2.0.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.0.rc1:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0.rc1:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-batch:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:2.1.4.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.3:test
[INFO] |  |     \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] |  |        \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.4:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.11.1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:2.27.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.9.13:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.6.2:test
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.thedumpster:correlation-id:jar:01.00.38:compile
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.thedumpster:common:jar:01.00.38:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.13.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.observability:metrics-spring-boot-starter-web:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.blahblah.observability:metrics-spring-boot-starter-core-servlet:jar:0.2.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.blahblah.observability:metrics-spring-boot-starter-core:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_hotspot:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.prometheus:simpleclient_servlet:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_common:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.prometheus:simpleclient:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.prometheus:simpleclient_hibernate:jar:0.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.blahblah.observability:metrics-spring-boot-starter-servlet-filter:jar:0.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-integration:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.4.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-core:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.batch:javax.batch-api:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-infrastructure:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.4.16:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.x-stream:mxparser:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.blah.batch:ls-batch-common-lib:jar:2.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-messaging:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sns:jar:1.11.125:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:jar:1.11.136:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.ion:ion-java:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.10.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-cbor:jar:2.12.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:jar:4.5.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:jar:4.4.11:compile
[INFO] +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.14:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sqs:jar:1.11.136:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:jmespath-java:jar:1.11.136:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-context:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-aws-core:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-s3:jar:1.11.598:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-kms:jar:1.11.598:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-ec2:jar:1.11.125:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-cloudformation:jar:1.11.125:compile
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.fs:super-juice:jar:1.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-sts:jar:1.11.136:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.6:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.avro:avro-compiler:jar:1.9.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.velocity:velocity-engine-core:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.postgresql:postgresql:jar:42.2.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.waffle:waffle-jna:jar:1.9.1:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna:jar:4.5.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  +- net.java.dev.jna:jna-platform:jar:4.5.2:runtime
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:jar:2.6.2:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.osgi:org.osgi.core:jar:4.3.1:runtime
[INFO] |  \- org.osgi:org.osgi.enterprise:jar:4.2.0:runtime
[INFO] +- com.blahblah.blah.sales:sales-offers-db:jar:02.00.03-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:2.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-aspects:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.zaxxer:HikariCP:jar:3.3.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-envers:jar:5.4.24.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.24.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.9.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.4.24.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.20.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:4.3.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.26:runtime
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.12.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.dozermapper:dozer-core:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring-boot-starter:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring4:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.github.dozermapper:dozer-spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:6.2.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.spockframework:spock-core:jar:1.1-groovy-2.4:test
[INFO] +- org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:jar:2.4.16:test
[INFO] +- cglib:cglib-nodep:jar:2.2.2:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.batch:spring-batch-test:jar:3.0.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.1.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |  \- org.powermock:powermock-module-junit4-common:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |     +- org.powermock:powermock-core:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] |     \- org.powermock:powermock-reflect:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO] \- org.powermock:powermock-api-mockito:jar:1.6.4:test
[INFO]    \- org.powermock:powermock-api-support:jar:1.6.4:test
```

Comment: You are mixing different version of frameworks. You are mixing Spring 5.1.6, 4.3.12, you are mixing Spring Boot 2.1.4 and 2.1.6 modules, Spring Batch 4.2.3 and 3.0.6, Tomcat 8.5.63 and 9.0.21. Jackson 2.8.10 and 2.10.0, 2.11.0.rc1 (why a non-final version here?!). And there are probably more. So in short your dependencies are a mess. Also judging by all those dependencies I doubt this is a "simple application".

Comment: @M.Deinum Haha, I guess you're right. I didn't realize I was mixing that many as I inherited this application. By simple, I mean't is size and use case, is rather small (not a huge application). But you're right dependencies are a mess. Let me try to fix now, thanks!

Comment: @M.Deinum in this pom, I have alot of individual dependencies declared seperately. - like hibernate, jpa, etc... would it make sense or be a better option to use. the "spring-boot-starter" type dependencies , like for JPA, because then it would pull all the other dependencies like hibernate for me with the correct version right?

Comment: Correct. But there is more at hand as you have a lot of mixed dependencies (all leading to trouble in the end). But using the starters over the individual jars will help.